# Interchanging $\limsup$ and $\sup$

Tags: limits

Let $f_n: \mathcal{X} \to [0,1]$ be a sequence of functions and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

I want to show that

$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f_n(x) \leq \alpha
$$

implies

$$
\sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \leq \alpha
$$

but my $\limsup$'s are a little rusty. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, for each $n$, $$m_n=\sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f_n(x)$$ Then, for every $x$ in $\mathcal X$ and every $n$, $$f_n(x)\leqslant m_n$$ hence, for each given $x$ in $\mathcal X$, $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\leqslant\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}m_n$$ This inequality holds for every $x$ in $\mathcal X$, hence, as desired, $$\sup_{x\in\mathcal X}\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\leqslant\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}m_n$$

Comment: Much more elegant than my answer :-) (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $$\sup_{x\in X}\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)>\alpha .$$
Then, there is $y\in X$ s.t. $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(y)>\alpha ,$$
i.e. there is $N$ s.t. $$\sup_{k\geq n}f_k(y)>\alpha.$$ for all $n\geq N$.

But $$f_k(y)\leq \sup_{x\in X}f_k(y),$$ i.e., if $n\geq N$ $$\alpha <\sup_{k\geq n}f_k(y)\leq \sup_{k\geq n}\sup_{x\in X}f_k(x).$$
Therefore $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\sup_{x\in X}f_n(x)>\alpha .$$
Contradiction.